# PostgreSQL 9.3: Count all tables contained in view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to count the number of `tables` which is contained by a `view`.

In SQL Server I do it like this:

```
Declare v_tables int

SELECT  v_Tables = Count(*)
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
      WHERE View_Name = View1;
```

How about PostgreSQL 9.3 ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, because Postgresql has INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Are you wanting this in a stored procedure?

Comment: @mlinth, Yeah! Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_tables(p_viewname text) RETURNS integer AS $BODY$
  SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.view_table_usage
  WHERE view_name = p_viewname;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT;
```